# Get sortable instance from ng-sortable directive in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-sortable

How can I get the sortable instance from a ng-sortable directive (https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/blob/master/ng-sortable.js) without a reference? I expected something like this to work, but it doesn't (`option is not a function`):

```
angular.element(element[0].querySelector('ol')).option('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This kind of comments is neither helpful nor respectful. Flagged.

Comment: Your code has typo? where is opening brackets of `).option`?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? and what have you done so far? Can you share a plnkr or some code?

Comment: @maximski My comment was flagged and deleted from this question, I don't know what was inappropriate about it - I didn't use any swearwords and just gave you an example from the manual relevant to the original post. I'm sorry if you found that offensive, it wasn't my intention

Comment: @AlonEitan If you tried for like two full days to get this to work with various approaches and not only know every single word from the readme with closed eyes but have also analyzed pretty much every single line of the plugin code, you don't want to hear clever tips from anyone like "read the manual".

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because the ng-sortable plugin doesn't provide a reference to the created Sortable instances. I ended up writing an own Sortable directive which utilizes jQuery so I can approach the Sortable instance via that.